# Distinguish tr in dynamic table form for serializing jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a dynamic table with same names of form parameters. 
I need to get the parameters as separate rows for insertion in database using $_POST in PHP page.

**HTML**

```
<section id="table_params_form">
        <form>
            <table id="table_params">

                <tr>
                    <td><select id="selectcs" name="selectcs[]">
 *--value options --*
                    </select></td>

                    <td><select id="selectprts" name="selectprts[]">
 *--value options--*
                    </select></td>

                    <td><select id="selectnds" name="selectnds[]">
 *--value options --*
                    </select></td>

                    <td><input type="text" name="lcl[]" value="0"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ucl[]" value="0"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
        <section>
```

The jQuery below appends tr id to each row, but it actually does not help to get the POST values as separate rows.
Is there any solution to get these values for database insertion in PHP page?

**jQuery**

```
          formData = $("#table_params_form").serialize();

         $('#table_params').find('tr').each(function(){
           formData += '&' + this.id + '=row'+(i+1);
           i++;
          });

        $.post("saveParams.ajax.php",(formData ))
```

Comment: Given that all the controls have the same name, surely you can figure out which row is which by the index of the resulting arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that ID. `form.serialize` is enough. You can loop data like:

```
foreach ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['selectcs']); $i++) {
    var_dump($_POST['selectcs'][$i]);
    var_dump($_POST['selectprts'][$i]);
    var_dump($_POST['selectnds'][$i]);
    var_dump($_POST['lcl'][$i]);
    var_dump($_POST['ucl'][$i]);
}
```